# Complex Line Integral(Meromorphic)

Tags: complex-analysis

I used partial fractions to separate the denominator but I can't figure out what the purpose of splitting the function into two integrals is. I don't think they are analytic continuations of the other but I could be wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use: Cauchy Integral Formula and Residue Calculus

Partial fractions can be used, but will probably not be necessary.I will give you an example that will help you quickly solve this.

Ex: $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int _{|z|=3} \frac{1}{(z-1)(z-4)} dz $

Only one of the singularities fall within our contour so we can thus integrate instead:

$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{|z|=3} \frac{\frac{1}{z-4}}{z-1} dz = f(1) = \frac{-1}{3}$ by Cauchy Integral Formula. Here we take $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-4}$.

$\textbf{Question for OP}$: Does this make sense? Here we have a simple pole, order 1.

$\textbf{Additional}$: now in the case where we are integrating over a contour that gets both of singularities or if the function has more, we can use partial fractions to make our integral simpler and use Cauchy Integral however many times evaluating $f(z_0)$ where $z_0$ is the singularities for the function.Now this can be very tedious, but once one start to learn about residue calculus, the idea of having a function with a good bit of singularities becomes very much like child's play. Check this out [residue calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).

Comment: We would have a simple pole at root 2, -root 2, and z? How would I go about calculating the strengths of the poles?

Comment: Yes, and the strength of a pole can be easily determine once you have the denominator in the form $z-z_0$ for $z_0$ being your singularity and it would appear here that all have order $1$.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the clarification. One last question. How would I determine if the functions are analytic continuations?

Comment: I do not exactly know the answer to that question and I will nor pretend I do , but check out this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation. And I'm glad I could help. I hope this answer sufficed.